# What's the difference between wp_insert_user() and wp_create_user()

Tags: performance, user-registration, wp-create-user

I know the former allows additional parameters, so you can more user info, but other then that, why do both exist?

The specific reason I want to know is that wp_insert_user() is happening REALLY slowly. Somewhere between 5 - 10 seconds. I don't remember having this problem in the past, when I was using create_user, so I'm wondering if there's a lot more happening behind the scenes with one as opposed to the other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None. The whole source of `wp_create_user()` is:

```
function wp_create_user($username, $password, $email = '') {
    $user_login = esc_sql( $username );
    $user_email = esc_sql( $email    );
    $user_pass = $password;

    $userdata = compact('user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass');
    return wp_insert_user($userdata);
}
```

It just calls *insert* version almost immediately, basically a shorthand wrapper. As for why it exists - core works in mysterious ways and (short of hunting down developer by version control history and asking) there is rarely way to tell. :)

Comment: Incorrect. It's NOT a direct alias. `wp_create_user` accepts three parameters, `wp_insert_user` accepts and array of data allowing you to set things like name, nicename, role, etc.

Answer (score 12):

As per Codex

> The wp_create_user function allows you to insert a new user into the
>   WordPress database. It uses the $wpdb class to escape the variable
>   values, preparing it for insertion into the database. Then the PHP
>   compact() function is used to create an array with these values. To
>   create a user with additional parameters, use wp_insert_user().

So the main difference would be that with `wp_insert_user` you may pass more than just `($username, $password, $email)`. A full list of all the additional parameters for wp_insert_user can be found on its [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)

Comment: This is the correct answer.